# Mobile frameworks for ASP.NET (better open source)

Tags: asp.net, mobile, frameworks, mobile-website

The question is simple, What mobile frameworks are you using in ASP.NET?

We are using Mobile Controls + WURFL.

Thx in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used a combination of mobile controls, custom scripts, [MDBF](http://mdbf.codeplex.com/), [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/), [DeviceAtlas](http://deviceatlas.com/) and more.

[hawhaw.net](http://www.hawhaw.de/) also looks interesting, but haven't had a chance to check it out yet.

Comment: I have looked hawhaw.net, but i think it is very initial fase

Answer (score 0):

We are using **http://www.51degrees.mobi/Products/NETMobileAPI** it is a free open source .net mobile api which gives detailed information of the mobile device making the request. It makes use of WURLF database. Along with this it also provide free mobile controls which includes Google Maps, Location, Image and Adsense Controls

Comment: I don´t know it, i will look into it. Thx